# CS CART call a controller at add on front end with microformat ajax

Tags: cs-cart

I am very new to cs cart. I have read their documentation about calling Ajax with form micrformats. I am able to create a Ajax request. But I would like to call a controller inside my add-on controllers/frondend/ directory names as `mycheckout.php`. I am using the a hidden file dispatch with the valu `mycheckout.mymode`. Can any one help me. I actually want to perform some action in my controller. But their documentation did not help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this (use extra "cm-ajax-force" or "cm-ajax-full-render" classes if needed):

```html
<form class="cm-ajax" name="your_name" action="{""|fn_url}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="result_ids" value="div_id_to_be_updated" />
    {include file="buttons/go.tpl" but_name="mycheckout.mymode" alt=__("Ajax button")}
</form>
```

Or you can use any button you want (even `<input type="submit" name="mychechkout.mymode" value="Ajax!">`)

Answer (score 0):

Note that the Ajax request can be also done via simple link:

```
<a class="cm-ajax cm-post" href="{"mycheckout.mymode?param1=value1&param2=value2"|fn_url}" data-ca-target-id="div_id_to_be_updated">Ajax!</a>
```